# Regex Special case: dont match perticular pattern in matched pattern

Tags: regex

I want to figure our regex for following type of texts:

Image **.png**

Hello **.jpeg**

Other **.jpg**

ThisDontMatch.jpeg

Explanation: String is matched because of Bolded substring

Requirement: Should match string ending with .jpeg or .jpg or .png but not match Specifically ThisDontMatch.jpeg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple solution, but it has the drawback working similar to a contains instead of an equal.

The regex below basically says find me any string that ends with png, jpeg, or jpg that does not contain the string `ThisDontMatch`.

`^((?!ThisDontMatch).)+\.(?:png|jpeg|jpg)$`

[Regex Example](https://regex101.com/r/yD9mQ1/2)

```
Image.png           <--- Match
Hello.jpeg          <--- Match
Other.jpg           <--- Match
ThisDontMatch1.jpeg <--- NO Match
ThisDontMatch.jpeg  <--- NO Match
```